# Debugging confusion for beginner in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Hi I am a beginner on Salesforce.com Platform

I've written an Apex class:

```
public class FieldSetDemonstration {

public Resource__c merch { get; set; }

public FieldSetDemonstration() {
    this.merch = getMerchandise();
}

public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
    return SObjectType.Resource__c.FieldSets.Hello2.getFields();
}

private Resource__c getMerchandise() {
    String query = 'SELECT ';
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
        query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
    }
    query += 'Id  FROM Resource__c LIMIT 1';
    System.debug('Hello world debug log');
    Resource__c res= Database.query(query);
    System.debug('Hello World Debug log'+''+res.name);
    return res;
}
}
```

this is a controller class 
in the visualforce page controller giving the right res.name value but in debug console i am getting only Hello world Debug log. Can any one please tell why its not showing res.name value in debug console. How to show it for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally i found instead of using res.name in System.debug() i have to use res.get('Name')

public class FieldSetDemonstration {

public Resource__c merch { get; set; }

public FieldSetDemonstration() {
    this.merch = getMerchandise();
}

public List getFields() {
    return SObjectType.Resource__c.FieldSets.Hello2.getFields();
}

private Resource_*c getMerchandise() {
    String query = 'SELECT ';
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
        query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
    }
    query += 'Id  FROM Resource*_c LIMIT 1';
    System.debug('Hello world debug log');
    Resource__c res= Database.query(query);
    System.debug('Hello World Debug log'+''+res.get('Name'));
    return res;
}
}

this code is working fine

Comment: You can cast the result of Database.query from `List<sObject>` to `List<Resource__c>` or (since you have the limit) just `Resource__c res = (Resource__c) Database.query(query);`. That way you'll be able to write without dynamic getters again.